# A question from NBHM regarding minimal and characteristic polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

I found the following question in NBHM paper:

Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ and $A^3=I,A\neq I$,then $A^2+A+I=O$.

Is the above statement true?

**My attempt**

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$.Since $A$ is a $3\times 3$ real matrix,it has a real root.Now,$m(x)| x^3-1$ as $x^3-1$ annihilates $A$,so $m(x)=0\implies x^3-1=0\implies x=1,\omega,\omega^2$.

Now,so $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$[Since $A$ has a real eigenvalue].

**Case 1** If $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ in $\mathbb C$.

Then the characteristic polynomial is $p(x)=(x-1)^3$ and so by Cayley-Hamilton theorem $A^3-A^2+A-I=O$.

But $A^3=I$,so $I-A^2+A-I=O$ which implies $A^2=A$ and hence $I=A^3=A^2=A$ but $A\neq I$ as given in question.So,this case is rejected.

**Case 2** The eigenvalue of $A$ are $1,\omega,\omega^2$.[since $p(x)$ has real coefficients]

Then $m(x)=(x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)=x^3-1$,so $m(x)$ cannot divide $x^2+x+1$ and hence $A^2+A+I\neq O$.

For a complete example one can take $A=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} &0 \\  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ .

I think my solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement and your justification are ultimately correct.

That said, your solution is longer than it needs to be. The question was whether the statement "If $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ and $A^3=I,A\neq I$,then $A^2+A+I=O$" is correct, and you are trying to show that this statement is not correct. To show that this statement is not correct, you only need to give an **example** (or otherwise prove the existence of an example) of an $A$ for which $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ and $A^3=I,A\neq I$, but $A^2 + A + I \neq O$.

So, the following is a complete answer:

> The statement is incorrect. For example,
> $$
> A = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} &0 \\  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> satisfies $A^3=I,A\neq I$, but $A^2 + A + I \neq O$.

Interestingly, you prove the (correct) stronger statement that there exists no matrices $A \in M_3(\Bbb R)$ for which $A^3 = I, A \neq I$, and $A^2 + A + I = O$.